# How to use an Android Handler to update a TextView in the UI Thread?

Tags: android

I want to update a `TextView` from an asynchronous task in an Android application. What is the simplest way to do this with a `Handler`?

There are some similar questions, such as this: [Android update TextView with Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658754/android-update-textview-with-handler), but the example is complicated and does not appear to be answered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several ways to update your UI and modify a `View` such as a `TextView` from outside of the UI Thread. A `Handler` is just one method.

Here is an example that allows a single `Handler` respond to various types of requests.

At the class level define a simple `Handler`:

```
private final static int DO_UPDATE_TEXT = 0;
private final static int DO_THAT = 1;
private final Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        final int what = msg.what;
        switch(what) {
        case DO_UPDATE_TEXT: doUpdate(); break;
        case DO_THAT: doThat(); break;
        }
    }
};
```

Update the UI in one of your functions, which is now on the UI Thread:

```
private void doUpdate() {
    myTextView.setText("I've been updated.");
}
```

From within your asynchronous task, send a message to the `Handler`. There are several ways to do it. This may be the simplest:

```
myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(DO_UPDATE_TEXT);
```

Comment: What about `Handler class should be static otherwise memory leaks might occur` warning?

Comment: please find the [**Blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) and this  answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407943/this-handler-class-should-be-static-or-leaks-might-occur-incominghandler) to get more insight on this

Comment: i recommend weakHandler here to avoid a leak.  https://github.com/badoo/android-weak-handler

Answer (score 4):

You can also update UI thread from background thread in this way also:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // write in onCreate function

//below piece of code is written in function of class that extends from AsyncTask

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(stringBuilder);
    }
});
```